# PlayReady for offline content protection in Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, playready

I want to protect my uploaded content after it is downloaded. [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/playready4/2016/10/26/does-azure-media-services-support-offline-mode/) link provides some pointers about doing that. The link refers to using a .ismv file for this. But as far as I know, the Media Encoder used to encode MP4 to Smooth Streaming is deprecated.

How to generate smooth streaming files given an MP4 file using Azure Media Services ? Also, since it only supports PlayReady, how to play it on other browsers which don't support PlayReady ?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation links below for information on offline DRM in Azure Media Services. These cover offline HLS and offline MPEG-DASH. The Smooth static encryptor has been deprecated in favor of using dynamic encryption.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-content-protection-overview
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/offline-widevine-for-android